# Am I using this comma correctly?

Tags: grammaticality, commas, sentence

I would like to link the following two ideas in one sentence:

1) "As a result wireless links are highly susceptible to environmental factors such as extreme temperature, atmospheric effects, and coexisting wireless networks."

2) "These factors are common in industrial networks."

To accomplish this, I created what I put in parentheses below with a comma (in brackets) to link the two ideas.  Is what I've done grammatically correct?  I'm worried that a comma isn't the correct thing to use here because of the preceding list.  If not how might I combined these two ideas so that the result is functionally equivalent to what I've attempted to do below?

- "As a result wireless links are highly susceptible to environmental
  factors such as extreme temperature, atmospheric effects, and
  coexisting wireless networks[,] factors common in industrial
  environments."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply write the combined sentence like this:

"As a result wireless links are highly susceptible to environmental factors such as extreme temperature, atmospheric effects, and coexisting wireless networks, common in industrial areas."

OR

"As a result wireless links are highly susceptible to environmental factors such as extreme temperature, atmospheric effects, and coexisting wireless networks, found commonly in industrial areas."